# Visual C++ compiler comparison to other C++ compilers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Does the C++ compiler in Visual Studio allow the use of all other functions from the C++ library? I assume you can do additional tasks since its from Microsoft, but does it still maintain the same integrity allowing me to use the same functions from the C++ library?

Comment: Without any specific question, I'll point you at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is probably going to get closed, but ...

1) Microsoft C++ implementations vary wildly with respect to standard conformance.

AFAIK, *NO* MS compiler fully supports C99.

Also, AFAIK, the conformance to C++11 isn't bad.

Here are a few good comparisions:

- http://www.aristeia.com/C++11/C++11FeatureAvailability.htm
- http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/

2) The Visual Studio is an excellent IDE.

3) If you want to program for the Microsoft program in a different language (for example, in ASP.Net or Silverlight), Visual Studio is arguably the best way to do it.

4) Finally, check out this article on MSVC support for C++11:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

PS:
Remember: C != C++.

If you want to program in a conformant C, you don't necessarily care about the latest Microsoft SDK's, and you don't care about the MSVS IDE, you're probably better off with gcc.

IMHO...

Comment: Also you'll need to use VS 2013 to get the broader C++11 support

Comment: Thanks so much. The direction you pointed me paulsm4 was very helpful with those links. I have some reading to do.